# I can only save one record per minute how do I remove this limit?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have created an application that saves data into an sql table located on a local server using ADO.Net with simple insert query. However it seems that the application or the server only accepts one record per minute. How can I make the table accept more records?
I am getting the following error message after breaking the code:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AppLog'

Here is a code snippet i use:

```
#region Sql Insert statement
try {
    if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
        Conn.Open();
    } else if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [AppLog] values('" + strbuff + "', '" + time + "','" + Processing + "','" + userName + "')", Conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Conn.Close();
    }


} catch (Exception ex) {
    //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}#endregion
```

This code is executed by a timer which i have set to 1000 ms
[image]

Comment: Have you tried bulk insert?

Comment: Why do you think it saves one record per minute - a code issue or some limitation imposed by DB admin? Can you share your code and error messages?

Comment: I'll add the code in a minute

Comment: Added code, Just like to add though I am learning both c# and sql server for the first time in, I use to code strictly with vb.net and well using access so I really do not understand a lot

Comment: How do you determine you can only insert one record a minute? Are you sure the problem isn't in your timer?

Comment: `if block` says, if connection is closed just `open` it and do nothing

Comment: I know it is adding only one record a minute because i made an insert statement that runs with this for an access database and the access database has more records in it than the sql e.g. access has 20 where as in the same amount of time sql will only have 1-2 each spaced out in 1 minute intervals will add screen shot

Comment: Put breakpoints, walk through all relevant code. I'd also try removing the word "else".

Comment: I thought it would be better to have both if statements running at the same time because when i didn't i had been getting "Connection is closed" and "Connect is open" error messages

Comment: There is nothing in this code snippet which would limit the number of records written to the database. You have to show us how this code is being called.

Comment: Its very long the code i mean.. It is as i said in the question being called from a timer but if you insist i can add it

Comment: What is your primary key column?

Comment: iTime is the primary Key

Comment: @Broken_Code I undid your edit because I think this version of the question is clearer

Comment: To whomever down-voted my question I want to know why and what I should do to fix whatever I did wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are having this error is because the column `ITime` is your primary key.

Primary keys are supposed to be unique in your table.

Currently, when you add a row, it adds the time it was added to the `ITime` column. For instance:

```
2014-06-10 16:32
```

When you try to add another row, it adds *the same time* to the `ITime` column, so you end up with this:

```
2014-06-10 16:32
2014-06-10 16:32
```

The problem is, because the `ITime` column is your primary key, *you cannot have duplicate values* of it in your table.

To fix this, either add a new column to be your primary key, or make the time more unique, for instance adding the time as ticks.

Comment: This definitely sounds like the most likely candidate. Date and time columns make very poor choices for primary keys. The goal with a key is that it should be as unique, always increasing, stable over time and as narrow as possible. Integer identity columns are widely use as [surrogate keys](http://sqlmag.com/business-intelligence/surrogate-key-vs-natural-key) for this very reason. It looks as though you are using `SHORTDATETIME` in your DB column. `DATETIME` would be better but really you need to stop using the date column as a primary key.

Comment: Oh Ok well this answer I understand so basically its stuck on the time that it first used and can not use any other time until the primary key value changes well that is depressing

Comment: This may seems like a very stupid question to ask but. How do i change my table in design view without deleting it and making a new one. I have tried before to change the primary key but it kept telling me that visual studio had a connection with it and i can not save any changes

Comment: @Broken_Code Please open a new question for that query and we will be more than happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `ITime` column as a primary key? This explains the one-record-per-minute issue since your time is restricted to minutes. Also; it says you have a primary key violation. This has nothing to do with performance etc.

Additionally; your if-block is very strange:

```
if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
    Conn.Open();
} else if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [AppLog] values('" + strbuff + "', '" + time + "','" + Processing + "','" + userName + "')", Conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Conn.Close();
}
```

If you have a closed connection you open it; otherwise you run a query and close it? Is this intended?

Comment: Ok but it adds information into the database per second not split second or minute how can having the datetime be a violation if the time is never constant.

Comment: @Broken_Code look at the time values in the database; there are no seconds or milliseconds there; just minutes.

Comment: :I know that which is why i am confused because in my access database i have the year month day hour minute and second. Here it does only adds the 00 second nothing else the code works fine in access how can the two be so different. Also I used that code because it adds information every second and when I do not use that code i get Connection is closed error or connect is open errors

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't serves as a complete answer, because your question is not complete.

However there are two important things to be fixed in the provided code:

1. When connection state becomes closed then you just leave the connection open without executing query.
   (Removed `else`).
2. Added [SqlCommand parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Changed Code in `try-catch` block:

```
if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
     Conn.Open();

if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
     cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [AppLog] values (@strbuff, 
                                                        @time, 
                                                        @Processing, 
                                                        @userName", Conn);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strbuff", strbuff);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", time);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Processing", Processing);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     Conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Ok what  else should I add to the question because I am still very new to c# and sql server so there are a lot of things I do not understand

Comment: You mentioned that code is executed by timer. Can you identify how?

Comment: Ok can you manually add similar `ITime` value in the db table?

Comment: what do you mean sililar itime value...?

Comment: Other Answers clearly explains that you cannot have duplicates in `ITime` Columns. As it is primary key. Hence the limit you are applying using Timer cannot be ignored.